# Match 2 dataframes based on 3 columns, fill the column with matched values, Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have df1 that looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       EVENT_TYPE       DAMAGE
   ALABAMA    1962       Tornado          27
   ALABAMA    1962       Flood            7
   ALABAMA    1963       Thunderstorm     12
...
```

and df2 that looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       TORNADO      THUNDERSTORM      FLOOD
   ALABAMA     1962       NaN          NaN           NaN
   ALABAMA     1963       NaN          NaN           NaN
...
```

And I want to merge these two dataframes together, so the final output looks like this:

```
STATE      YEAR       TORNADO      THUNDERSTORM      FLOOD   
  ALABAMA    1962       27           NaN              7
...
```

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

With the dataframes you provided:

```py
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "STATE": ["ALABAMA", "ALABAMA", "ALABAMA"],
        "YEAR": [1962, 1962, 1963],
        "EVENT_TYPE": ["Tornado", "Flood", "Thunderstorm"],
        "DAMAGE": [27, 7, 12],
    }
)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "STATE": ["ALABAMA", "ALABAMA"],
        "YEAR": [1962, 1963],
        "TORNADO": [None, None],
        "THUNDERSTORM": [None, None],
        "FLOOD": [None, None],
    }
)
```

Here is one way to do it using Pandas [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and Python [str.title](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.title) method:

```py
df3 = df2.copy()

for col in ["TORNADO", "THUNDERSTORM", "FLOOD"]:
    df3[col] = df3.apply(
        lambda x: df1.loc[
            (df1["STATE"] == x["STATE"])
            & (df1["YEAR"] == x["YEAR"])
            & (df1["EVENT_TYPE"] == col.title()),
            "DAMAGE",
        ],
        axis=1,
    )
```

Then:

```py
print(df3)
# Output
     STATE  YEAR  TORNADO  THUNDERSTORM  FLOOD
0  ALABAMA  1962     27.0           NaN    7.0
1  ALABAMA  1963      NaN          12.0    NaN
```